# Comparing four parameter in file

Tags: python, file

## Most profitable element for every category

Must read my file and determinate most profitable element for every category in range of dates by user entries.

**File:**

Date|Category|Name|Price

```
05/01/2016|category6|Name8|4200
06/01/2016|category1|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category3|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category1|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category3|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category2|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
08/01/2016|category2|Name1|1000
09/01/2016|category4|Name7|3100
```

My file will be a lot bigger this is just example.

Start Date : 07/01/2016
End Date: 07/01/2016

For every date in that range program will print most profitable element for every category

***Category 1:***

```
07/01/2016|category1|Name2|1200
```

Name2 = 1200

Comparing prices >>> Most profitable is: Name2

***Category 2:***

```
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category2|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
07/01/2016|category2|Name2|1200
```

Name1 = 1000
Name2 = 3600

Comparing prices >>> Most proftable: Name2

***Category 3:***

```
07/01/2016|category3|Name1|1000
07/01/2016|category3|Name2|1200
```

Name1: 1000
Name2: 1200

Comparing prices >>> Most profitable: Name2

Problem is i don't know how to compare these prices for categoris and names.
Also dates will be always on asending order.
I'm using both dictionary and lists.

***INPUT AND OUTPUT:***

Start Date : 07/01/2016

End Date: 07/01/2016

Category1; Most profitable is: Name2

Category2; Most profitable is: Name2

Category3; Most profitable is: Name2

in this case most profitable is Name2 for every category.

Comment: How about you use a dict of dates -> dict of category -> tuple. The tuple can contain the name and profit(?). You can compare the profit before inserting into the dict.

Comment: I'm not very good with dict started learning them this year. Know to do some easy stuffs, this is easy too but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @RedIcon Can you edit your question because your goal is actually to find the most highest price. Secondly, can you clarify the start date and end date? Are you planning to give input it each time, and is it inclusive of both start and end dates? Do you want to find the most expensive product for every day in the range or over the whole range?

Comment: @imp9 Yes i need to find most highest price but program must print like i said most profitable for every category. I will give two inputs, Start date and End date.

Comment: @RedIcon according to your example, the most profitable is the highest price.

Comment: Yes. But i need to calculate highest prices and print most profitable name.

Answer (score 1):

The following is not exactly what you need but should give you a fair idea to get going. I keep track of the most profitable name and value for combinations of date and category:

```
date_cat_profit_dict = {}

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # split and store into variables.
        # You could skip processing line
        # if you are looking for specific date
        date, category, name, profit = line.split('|')
        # Convert to int for comparison
        profit = int(profit)
        # Key for storing into dict
        composite_key = '{0}|{1}'.format(date, category)
        # _ because we don't need the name right now
        _, max_profit = (date_cat_profit_dict.
                         setdefault(composite_key, ('', 0)))
        if max_profit < profit:
            date_cat_profit_dict[composite_key] = (name, profit)

for composite_key, (name, profit) in date_cat_profit_dict.items():
    print('Max for {0} : {1}, {2}'.format(composite_key, name, profit))
```